# Understanding call by value-result and call by reference differnce

Tags: parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pascal, semantics, pass-by-const-reference

So I have this piece of Pascal code:

```
program P;

var a: array [1..2] of Integer;
var i :Integer;
var k :Integer;

procedure update(x,y,z: Integer);
    begin
        x := x+1;
        y := x*2;
        x := y;    
        k := x;
     end


begin
     a[1] := 5; a[2] := 10;
     k := 3;
     for i:=1 to 2 do
       begin
          update(a[i],a[2],k);
          print(a);
          print(k)
       end
end.
```

(assume that 'print' prints elements of array separated by spaces, and then prints a new line and also for an integer it just prints it)

And i'm trying to understand how different the output would be if the function call was by value-result or by reference.

obviously, if it was just by-value, it's easy to tell that the procedure wouldn't make any difference to the actual parameter, i.e the output (in by value) should be: 5 10 3 5 10 3.

I think that if it was be value-result it would have been, at least the first iteration: 12 12 12.
at the case of by reference I got confused.
What would it be?

Comment: Why is this tagged C++ and not Pascal?

Comment: sorry, my bad, although it doesn't really make a difference as the subject of the question has nothing to do with the language it's written in.

Comment: You included code so the tags absolutely make a difference.

Comment: What happens when you try it? If you do so, you'll clearly see the difference. (Also, the tag is entirely relevant when you post code. It's usually a good idea to pay attention to advice you receive here, especially when it comes from people with a considerable amount of experience here. You'll get answers much more quickly if you tag it in accordance with the language of the code you've posted; people who are familiar with that language will see it, and it's relevant for future readers of this site when searching for information.)

Comment: To illustrate the difference, write your `print` function to output the array contents, remove the loop, and run the code in the sequence `print`, `update`, `print`, and compare the outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared any variable parameters. The variable `K` will be changed, but that doesn't count in this context and is generally considered bad practice.

```
PROGRAM ParamTest;

VAR
   A, B : Integer;

PROCEDURE TestProc(X : Integer; VAR Y : Integer; CONST Z : Integer);

BEGIN
   X := X + Z;
   Y := Y + Z;
END;

BEGIN
   A := 10;
   B := 10;
   TestProc(A, B, 5);
   WriteLn(A, ' ', B);
END.
```

- X : Call by value
- Y : Call by reference
- Z : Call by constant

The output of this program should be `10 15`.

With declaring `Z`as constant parameter you promise to the compiler that you don't change that value. The following procedure variant should give an error while compiling.

```
PROCEDURE TestProc(X : Integer; VAR Y : Integer; CONST Z : Integer);

BEGIN
   X := X + Z;
   Y := Y + Z;
   Z := Z + 1;
END;
```